# Серверы приложения не видят JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

С проблемой столкнулся неожиданно, так как раньше всегда конфигурировал проект тем же способом.

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolverView() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver view =
            new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    view.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    view.setPrefix("/views/");
    view.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return view;
}
```

Здесь я указываю пути до страниц

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView startPage() {
    ModelAndView model = new  ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("index");
    return model;
}
```

А здесь я вызываю страницу из контроллера.

Испытывал на двух серверах JBoss и GlassFish
GlassFish - сообщает об ошибке 404
JBoss тупо выводит путь к JSP `/course-scbd-1.0/views/index.jsp
До сегодняшнего дня я часто использовал эту конфигурацию и проблем не было. Но сегодня я начал использовать версию Spring 4.3.7 может в этом проблема?
А еще JBoss периодически кидает такой лог:

```
com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.getResources(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1362)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1331)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

То есть сервер сообщает об ошибке JSF которой в принципе быть не может, так как JSF не подключался, и подключаться не будет, что за напасть то такая товарищи?

Comment: А разве тут view.setPrefix("/views/") не должно быть так view.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/")? Обычно в папке WEB-INF лежат jsp. странички

Comment: Не обязательно, да если и в WEB-INF положить ничего не меняется

Comment: А у вас, выложен проект полностью, на каком нибудь ресурсе, что бы посмотреть, так сказать, общую картину?

Comment: @Евгений Тупиков, нет он только начат, всего-то базовая конфигурация, я ее решил проверить и тут такое. Я проблему то решил, путем переноса views в каталог main